# So i'm trying to make a discord bot that can send random pictures in a js format but i have no idea how to

Tags: discord.js

if(command === 'example'){

client.commands.get('exaple').execute(message, args);

```
message.channel.send('https://i.redd.it/6nkyme7ayi631.jpg');
```

module.exports = {

```
name: 'example',

description: "this is a test command",

execute(message, args, Discord){
    message.channel.send('https://i.redd.it/6nkyme7ayi631.jpg');
}
```

}

Comment: What is a js format?

Comment: uhhh idk tbh java script?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of image URLs and then pick a random item from the array to send

```js
// Example using numbers
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

// module.exports etc
const randomNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)]

// send the random number/url
// I'm using console.log() to avoid an error
console.log(randomNumber)
```

```js
// implementation
// assuming you're using separate files for each command
// and using the code snippet you gave

module.exports = {
    name: 'number',
    description: "picks a random number",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        // change this to your URLs
        numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

        // change the variable names if you want
        const randomNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)]
        // send the chosen item
        message.channel.send(randomNumber)
    }
}
```

Comment: tysm!! (fillinnggggg innn spaccdeee))

Comment: @karrot If this works then please accept it as correct so people know this question has been solved

Comment: im still trying to figure out where i place it in the code because im stoopid

Comment: @karrot I've edited my answer to show you where to put it. You will need to change it to your needs (variable names etc)